# interlock vs intersect, which one is precise?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, terminology

I would like to use word **interlock** for FIG.A

[image]

and not sure I could use it for FIG.B, is **insert or slide** better for FIG.B,
[image]

anyone could help with this?

Comment: What sentence are you trying to put the words into?

Comment: Your title says "intersect", but the question text asks about "insert".

Comment: Welcome to SE ELU. As you are a new user you may not realize that this site allows questions and answers to be improved, either by the poster or by others (subject to the poster rejecting any alteration). Now your question has attracted interest, but it doesn’t conform to our standards because you haven’t provided an example sentence with a gap for the word you are looking for. You can edit your question to provide that, and we’ll all be clearer about what you are after. Nobody is making any personal criticism, we are just trying to improve the overall Q & A. Please consider engaging with us.

Comment: Hello thank you for your support and guidance, I will improve it per your instruction so as everyone could better understand it, have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if the poster gave an example of the sentence in which he wishes to use *interlock* or *intersect*, but I agree with @LPH that neither would seem appropriate. However, given the apparent subject matter — general handicrafts — I would go for a single-syllabled, familiar, Anglo-Saxon word, rather than that @LPH suggested:

> **[slot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slot)** *(verb)*

For Fig. A I would write that ”one piece of wood slotted *into the other*”, whereas for Fig. B I would write the two pieces of wood slotted *into each other*.

It is worth mentioning that one of the examples in the Merriam-Webster definition I have linked to is:

> He slotted the piece of wood into the groove.

Comment: Interlock doesn't work because? It would mean a total fit between the two. See: interlocking floor tiles, for example. One of the boards does indeed intersect the other (geometry) but yes, one is slotted into the other. +1

Comment: To me *interlock* suggests that once in place they hook/fix into each other so they can't easily be removed. Although you do talk about jigsaw pieces interlocking (but this might be a marketing claim, or refer to pieces that can't be pulled apart on the plane, without lifting one).

Answer (score 0):

A description of this material reality is not, in my opinion best served by either of the terms "interlock" or "intercept". "Intercept", from a mathematical point of view, implies the existence of points that belong to both entities: no such truth applies here as this can only be said of the parallelepipeds made up of the boards "before an indentation has been made". "Interlock" does not apply directly, but is essential in completing the description. A term that seems to express this reality better is "*interpenetrate*".

> (**SOED**) **2** *v. i.* & *t.* Of two or more things: penetrate (each other).
> **3**  *v. i.* & *t.* (w. *with*) *Archit* Appear to penetrate (A moulding, etc.)

- The two boards interpenetrate one another by means of two deep rectangular indentations (one in each board) of a width equal to the the thickness of the boards, and because of the appreciable size of this thickness the two boards interlock perpendicularly to one another.

There is hardly any change in the verbal forms used ("*one deep rectangular indentation*") when an indentation is made in one of the boards only. A single indentation is, from the point of view of the resulting geometric figure, entirely equivalent  to two indentations  with a total length equal to  the length of a single indentation (only the solidity of the boartds is affected).

Comment: notch is a V-shaped indentation.

Comment: @Lambie It is mostly what you say, so I'll have to change that term; good remark!

Comment: thank you @LPH and lambie, I DO see some article, most of them use interlock, especially for FIG.A, I agree with LPH that "interlock" is enough for the description. I also get a little interesting that LPH use indentation for the slot, that I see on the article, my understanding is slot is better than indentation, because indentation may be a size other than slot, indentation is a little bit similar to " groove" if I understand it correctly. not sure FIG.B is OK to use "interlock" or just can use "slide or insert" more precisely. sorry if the format is not displayed properly. thanks again